# How to start process with output to log file?

Tags: crystal-lang

I try to do it this way, but nothing happens.

```
Process.new("app_name >> app_name.log")
```

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: the problem here is that `>>` is a shell operator. find out how to pass an fd or something for the new process' stdout instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this entirely within Crystal without spawning a shell using the `output` option of `Process.new`.

```
File.open("app_name.log", "a") do |file|
  Process.new("app_name", output: file)
end
```

Comment: In matter of fact this answer gives me what I want. With shell when I try to get `pid` of my process I get `pid` of logger process. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`Process.new` by default executes the given command directly without a shell, therefore shell extensions like pipes do not work. But it accepts an argument `shell`, which executes the command with `/bin/sh` if set to `true`.

```
Process.new("app_name >> app_name.log", shell: true)
```